# In my library function, "unrecognized selector sent to instance" occurs

Tags: ios, frameworks, .a

There is encrypt.a, which encrypts, and keyboard.framework, which uses encrypt.a
If use encrypt.a directly in the test program, no error occurs,
If call some function that uses encrypt.a in keyboard.framework, will get an error.

```
[encrypt InputDec:keyData_in:keyData_out::]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60400000a9f0
2017-10-13 15:42:59.240225+0900 Keyboard_Test[86225:2520435] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[encrypt InputDec:keyData_in:keyData_out::]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60400000a9f0'
*** First throw call stack:

(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105c391cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105054f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105cb9914 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105bbc178 ___forwarding___ + 1432
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105bbbb58 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Keyboard                            0x00000001049ea8d8 -[Keyboard submitEncData] + 376
    6   Keyboard                            0x00000001049ee3a2 -[Keyboard touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 4418
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001062db139 forwardTouchMethod + 347
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001062db203 -[UIResponder touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 49
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000106129d4f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2807
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010612b472 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4124
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001060d0802 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000106a02a50 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2809
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000106a055b7 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5957
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105bdc2b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105c7bd31 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105bc0c19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105bc01ff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105bbfa89 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010b2c89c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001060b3d30 UIApplicationMain + 159
    21  Keyboard_Test                       0x00000001046bf9cf main + 111
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109c9bd81 start + 1
    23  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you can show method prototype and its calling ?

Comment: oh! I found parts with different case. Thank you. :D